# Access Azure VM without using RDP or any other third party apps

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I have been told that there is another way to access an Azure VM without using RDP. What other ways are out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Cloud Shell to work with any WM using the command line (bash for Linux VMs and PowerShell for Windows WMs)

You can find common info about Azure Cloud Shell usage here: [Overview of Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview)

Connection flow for Windows WMs here: [Interactively log on to a remote VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart-powershell#interactively-log-on-to-a-remote-vm)

Connection to Linux VM here: [SSH into your Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart#ssh-into-your-linux-vm)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to existing answer, all the regular ways to manage virtual machines are available (winrm\ssh), you can also use custom script extension to run command on your virtual machines without exposing management endpoints on those vm (more secure, but less trivial).

You can also use `Invoke-AzVmRunCommand\az vm run-command invoke` to run commands on the vm directly (similar to custom script extension).

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-1.3.0